# Ajax POST corresponding to a curl POST command

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, curl

I have this command:

```
curl -vX POST --header "Content-Type: text/json" --header "Authorization:MediaPreCompute" -d @someFile.txt someURL
```

`someFile.txt` has the data to be posted.
say it has:

```
{       
    keys: [],
    observer: "someobserver",
    table: "soneTable"
}
```

How can I do the same post request in JavaScript using Ajax. I know it would be something like this.. but how can I send the header: Authorization?

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json",
url: 'someUrl',
data: {myJsonDataInFile}
});
```

And also if the curl command gives me some output on terminal after completing, How can I collect that output while doing the same using Ajax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you solved? i need to do the same thing